# No class def found ProxyBypassListSelector

Tags: java, soapui

I have this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/btr/proxy/selector/whitelist/ProxyBypassListSelector

I tried to find the jar, which suppose to have this class, but no luck. May be someone can help me?

Comment: just trying to run soapui tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download following zip file
[proxy_vole.zip](https://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/downloads/detail?name=proxy-vole_20131209_bin.zip&can=2&q=)

Extract the zip file to get proxy_vole.jar

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in POM.xml

`<dependency>`
`<groupId>com.btr</groupId>`
`<artifactId>proxy-vole</artifactId>`
`<version>20131209</version>`
`<scope>test</scope>`
`</dependency>`

Comment: This is not working for me. Here is the one that Worked with fixing my project: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-handler-proxy